# вынести Namespace вебсервиса в конфиг файл, с подтягиванием данных при старте приложения. Соединение SOAP в проекте .net framework

Tags: c#, soap, config

Всем привет. Есть клиент 1С, который синхронизирован с приложением через SOAP. К 1С я доступа не имею, как оттуда идут запросы не знаю. На принимающей стороне  у меня есть код: `[WebService(Namespace = "http://test-server/")]` Один и тот же проект разворачивается на тестовой среде и на продуктиве. Так же 1с дает запросы на тестовую среду и на продуктив вида: `http://test-server/1cMethod` на тестовый и `http://prod-server/1cMethod`на продуктиве. Из за этого мне приходится на тестовый сервер заливать одно приложение, потом менять неймспейс, перебилдивать и заливать на продуктив. Так дело не пойдет, есть ли возможность вынести значение этого namespace в конфиг файл? Знаю что namespace это не имя сервера, но ручки 1С я поменять не могу, поэтому надо подстроиться под их наименования. Пробовал сделать так:

```
<add key="SOAPNameSpaceValue" value="http://test-server/" />
```

в конфиг файле, а в классе синхронизации так:  `[WebService(Namespace = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SOAPNameSpaceValue"]]` , но после этого выдает ошибку:

> CS0182 – An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Вот, не знаю как победить. Любой совет будет полезен

Comment: Как вариант - [Директивы препроцессора](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives). Можете определить 2 конфигурации сборки и собирать сразу две. Это вряд-ли решение, но от редактирования кода каждый раз должно избавить. Просто SOAP - это что-то очень старое, я не шарю. :)

Comment: Ну да, тут сразу приходит в голову условная компиляция. / Однако, неймспейс вебсервиса вовсе не означает адрес, по которому он расположен. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3122486/5045688

Comment: `1с дает запросы ... вида: http://test-server/1cMethod` - это именно адрес? или неймспейс вшитый в 1с? Потому что неймспейс веб-сервиса не равен адресу!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это неймспейс вшитый в 1С. Да, я знаю что неймспейс не равно адресу, но реализовано так. Они просто берут название сервера и вставляют его в запрос, как неймспейс, а я уже на своей стороне подстраиваюсь под этот запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Походу это тупик, и выхода нет)

В аннотации должна быть только переменная типа const. Const должна быть известна при запуске приложения, т.е. ее нельзя получить из внешнего файла(конфига). И значит у нас 2 выхода, либо каждый раз пересобирать проект, либо менять "ручки" на стороне 1С.

Comment: То есть комментарии вы не читали?

Comment: прочитал. Но не совсем понял, как мне поможет условная компиляция. Если вы про нее.  Я же не могу ей выдать условие, что если запускаешься на одном сервере, выполняешь один участок кода, а если на другом, то другой. Или все же могу, и я неправильно поискал?

Comment: С помощью условной компиляции можно одновременно получать два (или больше) приложения с нужными настройками внутри.